# A Haskell function that takes two strings and filters the second according to the first

Tags: list, haskell, filter

The objective is: Using `foldr`, define a function *remove* which takes two strings as its arguments and removes every letter from the second list that occurs in the first list. For example, `remove "first" "second" = "econd"`.

If this function took a single character and a string, I would do:

```
remove a xs = foldr (\x acc -> if x /= a then x : acc else acc) [] xs
```

But I can't figure out how I am supposed to do this with two strings. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: use `elem`.

Comment: im stupid... thank you @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
remove xs ys = foldr (\x acc -> if elem x xs then acc else x : acc) [] ys
```

yep.

Answer (score 1):

```
remove :: String -> String -> String                       
remove xs ys = foldr (condCons) "" ys
  where
    condCons l rs | l `notElem` xs = l : rs
                  | otherwise = rs
```

It is also allowed to discard the 'ys' paramenter:

```
remove :: String -> String -> String                       
remove xs = foldr (condCons) ""
  where
    condCons l rs | l `notElem` xs = l : rs
                  | otherwise = rs
```

Basically, condCons takes a character L and a string Rs. If L is not an element of xs, then it cons to Rs, otherwise leave Rs unchanged. foldr takes the condCons, the intial string "", and the second argument ys. L takes on each character of the string ys from right to left, building a new string from "" using the condCons binary operator.